# How to Make A second API call based on the value gotten from the first. with React and useEffect hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to make a call to the first APi that contains a payload of different CATEGORIES and then use that to make a second call to another API that contains different category items from each CATEGORY from the first. I am new to react and don't quite know how to make the logic work. This is my idea below. Category items are displayed based on the selected CATEGORIES. I am confused on how to use the value from the first to make the second call.

```
const [catalog,setCatalog] = useState([]);
const [catalogItems,setCatalogItems]= useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async () => {

      await fetchMarketingCategories()

     .then((result)=>{

        setCatalog(result);

          console.log("result",result);
         
     })

     .then(async (categoryId)=>{
         
          const {items = []} = await getAdvisorMarketingCatalog(categoryId)

          setCatalogItems(items);
     })
     

    };
    fetchData();

    
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: In the response of your api you could make the another api call.

Answer (score 1):

Just use async await, don't use async await with `then`.

Just like this:

```js
useEffect(async () => {
  const result = await fetchMarketingCategories()

  setCatalog(result)

  console.log('result', result)

  // not sure how you want to get the id from result
  const categoryId = getCategoryIdFromResult(result)

  const { items = [] } = await getAdvisorMarketingCatalog(categoryId)

  setCatalogItems(items)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you what, but I will explain what am I doing below.

When my component loads, with the help of my first `useEffect` hook, I am fetching the first catalogs. These results are then rendered in the UI. When the user clicks on any of the catalogs I am setting its id in state and, with the help of my second `useEffect`, I am fetching the next result from API.

Here is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [catalog, setCatalog] = useState([]);
  const [catalogItems, setCatalogItems] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCatalog, setSelectedCatalog] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetchMarketingCategories();
      setCatalog(result);
      console.log("result", result);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDetails = async () => {
      const { items = [] } = await getAdvisorMarketingCatalog(selectedCatalog);
      setCatalogItems(items);
    };
    if (selectedCatalog) {
      fetchDetails();
    }
  }, [selectedCatalog]);

  return (
    <div>
      {catalog?.map((c) => (
        <div onClick={() => setSelectedCatalog(c.id)}>{c.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to fetch data based on previously fetched data and do it simultaneously. To do so one way can be:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
 try {
  const getCategories = await fetchMarketingCategories()
  setCatalog(getCategories)

  // Now if fetch1 gives you array of catalogs with id you can just use 
  // Array.map() to fetch catalog items. But this will ping a lot of request 
  // to the api. But if this is the only way you need to do then go ahead.
 
  let finalData = []
  finalData = getCategories.map(async (items, idx)=> {
   return await getAdvisorMarketingCatalog(items.id)
  })
  setCatalogItems(finalData)
 } catch (err) {
    // Do what you want with the error
 }
}
useEffect(()=> {
 let ignore = false
 
 if (!ignore) {
  fetchData()
 }
 
 return () => ignore = true
}, [])
```